# x-editable issue with select source

Tags: x-editable

I have a "select" type:

```
<a href="#" name="my_name" data-type="select">Blah</a>
```

I have it's values initialized in javascript:

```
$('a[name="my_name"]').editable({
    url: 'blah.php',
    name: 'my_name',
    source: [
            {value: 'Foo', text: 'Foo'},
            {value: 'Bar', text: 'Bar'}
    ]
 });
```

I disable the field on page load with this code: (I have a button that turns on the field whence clicked)

```
$(document).ready(){
    $('a[name="my_name"]').editable('disable');
});
```

The problem is the "source" values DO NOT get read in when 'enabling' the link. 
If I comment out the disable code on page load, the editable field works fine. Only when I first disable, and then enable does this happen. Any clues why?